# Windows: How to lock an FTP downloaded file

Tags: windows, ftp, download, locking

I have one application in which I download files from FTP server.

As the file is downloading, a third party begins uploading that file and so it ends up with a corrupt file and is unable to process it.

Does any know about how to deal with situation other than using .complete file mechanism? (keeping track of when the download is complete)

Is it possible to lock the file on the FTP server?  The FTP server is windows.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no standard locking mechanism, it's all between up to you and the other party. Here are some ways to do it in addition to creating a `.complete` file;

- The uploader uploads the file as `file.xls.tmp`, and when it's complete, rename to `file.xls`.
- The uploader uploads to a `tmp` directory, and when it's complete, moves it to the scanned dir.
- The uploader uploads the file, and the downloader scans file dates to find files written before a certain time. This is not as reliable, since a file from a crashed uploader may be scanned.

There are probably more versions, particularly with a custom ftp server, but using the plain standard doesn't allow for much "fancy stuff".

Comment: Yes, I have heard of all of above techniques but I was especially looking for locking mechanism.